# How do I stream audio from a URL for an iPhone app and change volume using AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am trying to stream audio for an iPhone app. With the AVPlayer, I can stream audio from a URL with a few lines of code. I cannot change the volume with the AVPlayer though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can change volume by property volume, see below code

```
NSString* resourcePath = url; //your url
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        audioPlayer.volume = 5.0f;  //set volume here
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: I am trying to stream audio for the app, not from a file. Therefore, I cannot use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Yes you can pass url to _objectData just like this  NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"http://a40.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/062/Music/ec/88/d0/mzm.fqrwrunh.aac.p.m4a"]];

Comment: It is for a live stream (radio station), not streaming a music file from somewhere else. It doesn't work for situations like live continuous streams.

Comment: Excuse me, I use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer and [avPlayer setVolume:0.5f]; does not work for me. I implemented an UISlider but not change the volume. The only volume change is with side buttons of iPod/iPhone. PLEASE, HEEEEEELP